# MySQL Query: Is there a better way to get users who are X years old or older based on birth_date date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently storing the user's date of birth as a `DATE` field with `0000-00-00` as default value.

I am using this query to get users who are 30 years or older for example.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myUsers
WHERE birth_date != '0000-00-00'    
AND DATE(birth_date) < DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 30 YEAR ) ) 
ORDER BY user_id desc LIMIT 0,10
```

Is this the correct sql query to get what I want? (Getting users who are older than or exactly 30 years old) And could it be improved/optimized in anyway?

Comment: DATE() prohibits the use of an index, so it would be more efficient to provide a range

Comment: I would use `<=` for this - as written, people whose 30th birthday is today would be excluded.

Comment: @Siyual this is one more operation to perform. it depends what op wants.

Comment: @inetphantom *...to get users who are 30 years or older...*  -- It's pretty clear in the requirement what the OP wants.  And the query is not going to be impacted by changing a `<` operator to a `<=`...

Comment: @Siyual _Getting users who are older than 30 years old_ and _who are over X years old_ are clear too, thats why I mention it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You both are correct, I meant " exactly or older than x ". thanks. Edited question and sorry for this mistake

Comment: As @Strawberry mentioned you shouldn't use `DATE(birth_date)` as soon `birth_date` is already a DATE field. Just use `birth_date`. in this case Index on this filed (if exists?) will be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always wrong, but I prefer not to store dates with `0000-00-00` as a default value, use NULL instead (unless it has a special meaning, and you have to distinguish it from NULL).

Then you are using the `DATE()` function to remove the time info from a datetime field, but since `birth_date` is not a datetime field there's no reason to use it. This can make use of an index if present.

You could then just use this query:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     myUsers
WHERE    birth_date <= CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 30 YEAR 
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

(if the default value is NULL there's no need to check for it). Just decide if you want to use `<` or `<=` but I prefer the latter since it will include people on their birthday.

It's then a good idea to have an index on birth_date and user_id fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `0000-00-00` values, use `BETWEEN` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myUsers
WHERE birth_date BETWEEN '0000-01-01' and CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 30 YEAR 
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```